# Как передать в С++ библиотеку указатель на объект из C# и затем получить данные обратно?

Tags: c#, c++, dll

Дело такое: Написал несколько функций на С++ и хочу их использовать в C# коде, но не знаю как правильно объявить эти функции в C#.

C функциями `int CreateNewConverter()` и `void DestroyConverter(/*in*/ int id)` вроде бы понятно, но вот `void Convert(int converterID, IDeckLinkVideoFrame *srcFrame, byte **dstArray))` вызывает сомнения в правильности оформления и удобства использования в C#, потому что у меня тут данные в библиотеку передаются и забираются через указатели.

Отмечу, что `IDeckLinkVideoFrame *srcFrame` это указатель на COM (Component Object Model) объект реализующий интерфейс `IDeckLinkVideoFrame, так что, я полагаю, наверное, можно передать его с помощью IntPtr, но я не знаю как.

Прошу помочь: укажите на ошибки, посоветуйте как правильнее, помогите решить.

**H-файл:**

```
#ifdef DLFC_EXPORTS
#define DLFC_API __declspec(dllexport) 
#else
#define DLFC_API __declspec(dllimport) 
#endif

using namespace std;

static unordered_map<int, VideoConverterARGB32*> Dictionary;

static int ID = 0;

extern "C" {
    DLFC_API int CreateNewConverter();

    DLFC_API void DestroyConverter( /*in*/ int id);

    DLFC_API void Convert( /*in*/  int converterID,
                           /*in*/  IDeckLinkVideoFrame *srcFrame,
                           /*out*/ byte **dstArray);
}
```

**CPP-файл:**

```
using namespace std;
int  CreateNewConverter() {
    ID++;
    VideoConverterARGB32* conv = new VideoConverterARGB32();
    Dictionary[ID] = conv;
    return ID;
}

void DestroyConverter(/*in*/ int id) {
    VideoConverterARGB32* conv = Dictionary[id];
    Dictionary.erase(id);
    delete conv;
}

void Convert(/*in*/  int converterID,
             /*in*/  IDeckLinkVideoFrame *srcFrame,
             /*out*/ byte **dstArray)
{
    VideoConverterARGB32* conv = Dictionary[converterID];
    conv->Convert(srcFrame, dstArray);
}
```

**С#:**

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using DeckLinkAPI;

namespace AR.CaptureDevices.DeckLink {
    public class DeckLinkConverter {
        [DllImport(dllName: "DeckLinkConverter")]
        public static extern int CreateNewConverter();

        [DllImport(dllName: "DeckLinkConverter")]
        public static extern void DestroyConverter([Out] int id);

        [DllImport(dllName: "DeckLinkConverter")]
        public static extern void Convert([In]int converterID, [In] IDeckLinkVideoFrame* srcFrame, [Out] byte** dstArray);

    }
}
```

Comment: `unsafe` при работе с указателями ?

Comment: Массив надо объявлять: `MarshalUnmanagedType.ArrayByValud` с параметром `out`. Название типа написал по памяти, наверняка ошибся ,:) перепроверьте пожалуйста.

Comment: Я вижу, что вы пишите декомпрессор... изображений или чего? Вы можете воспользоваться Handle-ами, для передачи информации. HBTIMAP HWND и другие хандлы там и там имеют силу. Ещё посмотрите библиотеку GDIPlus возможно там уже есть реализация нужного алгоритма.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Есть несколько вариантов.

1. Самый простой вариант - получение ссылки

   ```
   List<string> list1 = new List<string>();
   GCHandle handle1 = GCHandle.Alloc(list1);
   IntPtr parameter = (IntPtr) handle1;
   // call WinAPi and pass the parameter here
   // then free the handle when not needed:
   handle1.Free();

   // back to object (in callback function):
   GCHandle handle2 = (GCHandle) parameter;
   List<string> list2 = (handle2.Target as List<string>);
   list2.Add("hello world");
   ```

Полученная ссылка для чистого массива - будет указывать на массив (скорее всего).

Плюс в `Marshal` есть много полезностей, например: `ReadByte`, `WriteByte`, `PtrToStringAnsi`, `StringToBSTR`, `Copy` и другие.

Ccылка http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17339928/c-sharp-how-to-convert-object-to-intptr-and-back

2. Использование COM (ActiveX). Создаём COM-совместимый класс, и работаем в с++ как обычно работают с подобными обьектами. Если наследовать один из извесных интерфейсов - то будет совместимость с ним. "Тунели" с# сам создаёт при использовании COM-совместимых типов.

Для передачи указателя на интерфейс, в  `Marshal` есть `GetComInterfaceForObject`.

ссылка http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/612604/Best-Practice-in-Writing-a-COM-Visible-Assembly-Cs

Так же, если есть интерфейс в с++, то можно его подхватить на с# по ссылке, используя `Marshal.GetTypedObjectForIUnknown`.

Так же можно передавать COM автоматически, для этого нужно, что б интерфейс был помечен как COM

```
[ComVisible(true)]
public interface IDeckLinkVideoFrame :IUnknown {
  //...
  }
```

И процедура вызова с с++ была в с# обьявлена примерно так

```
 [DllImport(dllName: "DeckLinkConverter")]
 void Convert(
    [In][MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]int converterID, 
    [In][MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)]IDeckLinkVideoFrame srcFrame, 
    [Out][MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] byte **dstArray);
```

3. C++-CLI. Данная модель позволяет обьеденить интерфейсы с# и с++, что то среднее что одной ногой в c# а другой в с++.
   https://habr.com/post/47732/

Comment: Отличная информация! На моё счастье, объект, который я хочу передать, уже является COM-объектом. Значит мне нужно всего лишь использовать `GCHandle.Alloc(myCOM_obj);`. Но возникает вопрос: как же тогда должна выглядеть функция в нативной библиотеке, которая принимает этот `IntPtr`? Какие у неё должны быть параметры? И как мне правильно объявить эту функцию в C#? Что писать в []?

Comment: Нет, нужно создать обьект с пометкой [ComVisible], и получить Ptr на интерфейс через `Marshal.GetComInterfaceForObject(obj,typeof(IDeckLinkVideoFrame))`, и подставить его, например сюда `IDeckLinkVideoFrame *srcFrame` в сам аргумент. А... стоп, позможно и ничего не нужно делать (это ручной проброс)... сейчас минутку, нужно добавить атрибуты, и с# свяжет интерфейс автоматом.

Comment: Нужно `[MarshalAs()]` и проставить "типы аргументов". Тогда с# сам свяжет.

Comment: Думаю так `public static extern void Convert([In][MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]int converterID, [In] [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)]IDeckLinkVideoFrame srcFrame, [Out][MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] byte **dstArray);`  Два последних маршала...  не уверен. Пробовать нужно. Вместо dstArray, я бы сделал IntPtr - что б тогда с unsafe не морочится. А лучше погуглить ещё как на с# массив принять....